# SP2013 unknown reason for access issues

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, permissions, security

I added an AD user to group "Site Members" in a SharePoint 2013 application. Group "Site Members" has Contribute permissions at the site root, and there are no restrictive permissions listed when clicking "View Group Permissions" at the site root.  This user cannot access the site root.  I don't know where to look at this point - I don't see logs pertaining to site object access.

What else is available to troubleshoot, or where can I look for more detailed information?

Comment: Does he gets some error ? When he tries this URL, does he gets the Login prompt ? What happens after passing correct credentials ? What browser is he using ?

Comment: Same error every time. He is not prompted for credentials: Windows Based authentication AD account matches the user added to group "Site Members." He receives the friendly page that says he can request access to the page by providing a reason.  Even if he sends and I accept this request through "Site Settings | Access invitations and requests" as a Collection and Site Administrator the user still cannot get gain access. This happens for multiple browsers.

Comment: Hmmmm....Try giving him direct access i.e. from outside the group. Check if there is nothing wrong with his AD account.

Comment: Access failed after adding "Contribute" permissions to the user directly at the site root.  I can't check the user account as I am not a system administrator but I know the user can log in to a Windows box with their AD account.

Answer (score 0):

1. Verify user is logging on with proper credentials, sometimes users use incorrect domain when logging into SP causing this kind of issue, so they use e.g. `corp.local\myaccount`, while the actual permission in SP has been given is `corp\myaccount`.
2. Use Fiddler to determine if some specific resource on the site (such as style sheet) hasn't been published or user doesn't have permission on the item, so run Fiddler on user machine when logging on, and look at red rows in Fiddler that indicate inaccessible resources